# How do I calculate the mean and SEM of different measured parameters in a table using data organized into subcategories?

Tags: r

I am new to R, so I apologize if this has been asked before, but I was wondering how I can get R to take my data like this:

```
Tissue  Strain  Mouse  Parameter1  Parameter 2
 1       1       1      80.10       93.60
 1       1       2      86.70       91.30
 1       1       3      80.10       89.20
 1       1       4      82.30       90.70
 1       1       5      83.60       93.30
 1       2       6      79.60       88.20
 1       2       7      84.00       91.50
 1       2       8      73.80       93.10
 1       2       9      83.70       93.20
 1       2       10     83.90       92.40
 2       1       1      84.40       53.80
 2       1       2      88.40       47.30
 2       1       3      88.70       45.70
 2       1       4      83.90       48.80
 2       1       5      81.90       56.80
 2       2       6      87.00       44.80
 2       2       7      87.50       43.20
 2       2       8      88.30       49.80
 2       2       9      89.20       41.60
 2       2       10     89.80       39.30
```

and produce a table that looks like this:

```
                Parameter 1 Parameter 2 
Tissue  Strain  Mean  SEM   Mean  SEM
1       1       82.56 1.23  91.62 0.82
2       1       81.00 1.98  91.68 0.92
3       1       85.46 1.33  50.48 2.08
1       2       87.28 0.52  43.74 1.77
2       2       83.92 0.75  57.06 3.14
3       2       86.16 0.76  56.38 2.85
```

I saw previous threads using aggregate and dplyr but they don't quite look like what I need (or maybe I am not understanding it well). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't have grouped columns in a data frame if that is what you are after. You might get by with *param1.Mean*, *param1.SEM* and alike. Everything else is formatting and depends where you want all that and how badly you want it that way. Also usually you would have a column *Parameter* that would have either 1 or 2 values...and just 2 columns for Mean and SEM. This is called long/molten(from melt), stacked, or unpivoted representation. Many graphing functions would prefer that over wide/cast/unstacked/pivoted form.

Answer (score 1):

One straight-forward way is using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Tissue, Strain) %>%
  summarize_at(
    vars(Parameter1, Parameter2),
    funs(mean, sem=sd(.)/sqrt(length(.)))
  )
# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# Groups: Tissue [?]
#   Tissue Strain Parameter1_mean Parameter2_mean Parameter1_sem Parameter2_sem
#    <int>  <int>           <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1      1      1           82.56           91.62      1.2327206      0.8230431
# 2      1      2           81.00           91.68      1.9811613      0.9216290
# 3      2      1           85.46           50.48      1.3298872      2.0826426
# 4      2      2           88.36           43.74      0.5182663      1.7668050
```

---

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
Tissue  Strain  Mouse  Parameter1  Parameter2
 1       1       1      80.10       93.60
 1       1       2      86.70       91.30
 1       1       3      80.10       89.20
 1       1       4      82.30       90.70
 1       1       5      83.60       93.30
 1       2       6      79.60       88.20
 1       2       7      84.00       91.50
 1       2       8      73.80       93.10
 1       2       9      83.70       93.20
 1       2       10     83.90       92.40
 2       1       1      84.40       53.80
 2       1       2      88.40       47.30
 2       1       3      88.70       45.70
 2       1       4      83.90       48.80
 2       1       5      81.90       56.80
 2       2       6      87.00       44.80
 2       2       7      87.50       43.20
 2       2       8      88.30       49.80
 2       2       9      89.20       41.60
 2       2       10     89.80       39.30')
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you can do it in one line with the `plyr` package as follows. This is an example using the `iris` dataset:

```
ddply(iris, .(Species), summarise, MeanLength = mean(Sepal.Length), SdLength = sd(Sepal.Length))
```

Which returns:

```
 Species MeanLength  SdLength
1     setosa      5.006 0.3524897
2 versicolor      5.936 0.5161711
3  virginica      6.588 0.6358796
```